# Getting Pending Request on HTTP Client Response while ataching multiple files

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-8, guzzle, guzzle-service-description

I am facing an issue while sending API requests to by HTTP Client. I am getting a Pending Request. How to fulfill the response and get the response data from `$response->collect()`

here is my code:

```
public function postMultipleFiles($url, $files, $params)
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => auth()->check() ? 'Bearer '.auth()->user()->api_token:''
    ]);

    foreach($files as $k => $file)
    {
        $response = $response->attach('images['.$k.']', $file);
    }

    $response->post($this->base_url.$url, $params);

    return response()->json($response->collect());
}
```

The error I am getting

```
message: "Method Illuminate\\Http\\Client\\PendingRequest::collect does not exist."
```

Comment: The error message explains everything, the $response is a GuzzleHttp Response class object and it does not belong to a Laravel Collection, If you want to convert to collection get the response as array and use `an array

Comment: Yes Ik know but i am trying to figure to get the `$response->collect()` I am getting this error because of multiple files attachement